# Display FQDN instead of hostname in `docker node ls` output

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

When I run `docker node ls` command on swarm cluster the result looks as follows

```
ID                            HOSTNAME            STATUS              AVAILABILITY        MANAGER STATUS      ENGINE VERSION
0yy1e9u4gl7hipgvltffxv0pn *   host1               Ready               Active              Leader              18.09.5
413mv8n6rd9j2nt48km16mta6     host1               Ready               Active                                  18.09.5
```

The problem is that both servers have the same hostname but differs in the domain name. Is there a way to make swarm use FQDN instead of hostname for node identification? I assumed that it isn't possible but then I stumbled upon [this tutorial](https://blog.codeship.com/running-services-within-docker-swarm/) where the command's output appears to be exactly what I'm looking for. Do you know how I can achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on what the nodes `hostname`'s are set too.

By default `docker node ls` displays the short hostname (e.g. `hostname`) rather than the FQDN (e.g. `hostname -f`). You can set the short `hostname` to the value of the FQDN i.e.: `sudo hostname $(hostname -f)` (**note**: this is effective only until the next reboot - `man hostname` for additional details) and update `/etc/hostname` i.e: `hostname -f |sudo tee /etc/hostname` then `docker node ls`:
[image: manager node fqdn]

Wash, rinse and repeat for all your nodes and you should be good:
[image: all nodes fqdn]

**Update**: using [`swarmkit`](https://github.com/docker/swarmkit) you can set arbitrary `hostname`'s when joining the `swarm` cluster:
[image: swarmkit node]

It's not possible to set the `hostname` when joining the `swarm` using [`docker swarm join`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/swarm_join/).

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. I understand that docker uses output of `hostname` command by default and that I can manipulate it. I'm just curious if I can make docker use `hostname -f` instead. What I'm trying to achieve is to have `hostname` produce `host1`, `hostname -f` - `host1.example.com` and docker identify each node by `host1.example.com` and `host1.example2.com`. I suspect that it might not be possible and I'll have to use the solution you wrote about.

Comment: Hi @threaz, it might be possible using `swarmd` directly when joining the nodes to the manager by passing the [`--hostname`](https://github.com/docker/swarmkit/blob/master/cmd/swarmd/main.go#L65) parameter i.e. `swarmd -d /tmp/node-1 --listen-control-api /tmp/node-1/swarm.sock --hostname node-1` from the [`README.md`](https://github.com/docker/swarmkit/blob/master/README.md#L124). It's not possible to set the hostname when joining the swarm using [`docker swarm join`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/swarm_join/).